# How to define binds for class objects in python?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, binding

I'm trying to define bind button for class objects which are created in function.
Therefore, I write simple code here. When I press "Line button", it creates new instance in class method. In "**init** method" I'm verifying it. However, when I press right click(Button 3), it gives error. It is unable to reach class instances that I created in "create_line" function. How can I solve this problem? I'm also open to other ideas, like defining bind function in class maybe?

```
from tkinter import *

class line_class():

    def __init__(self,line_no):
        self.line_number=line_no
        print(self.line_number)

    def settings_menu(self, event):   
        print(self.line_number, ": line entered")

def create_line():
    A=line_class(my_canvas.create_line(200, 200, 100, 100, fill='red', width=5, capstyle=ROUND, joinstyle=ROUND))
    
root = Tk()
root.title('Moving objects')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('1200x600+200+50')
root.configure(bg='light green')

my_canvas = Canvas(root, bg='white', height=500, width=700)
my_canvas.pack()

btn_line = Button(root, text='Line', width=30, command=lambda: create_line())
btn_line.place(relx=0,rely=0.1)

root.bind("<Button-3>",A.settings_menu)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First when `root.bind("<Button-3>",A.settings_menu)` is executed, `A` is not created yet.  Second, `A` is a local variable inside `create_line()` so it cannot be accessed outside the function.

I would recommend to define the binding inside `line_class`, and use `my_canvas.tag_bind(...)` instead of `root.bind(...)`:

```py
from tkinter import *

class line_class():
    def __init__(self,line_no):
        self.line_number=line_no
        print(self.line_number)
        
        my_canvas.tag_bind(line_no, "<Button-3>", self.settings_menu)

    def settings_menu(self, event):   
        print(self.line_number, ": line entered")

def create_line():
    line_class(my_canvas.create_line(200, 200, 100, 100, fill='red', width=5, capstyle=ROUND, joinstyle=ROUND))
    
root = Tk()
root.title('Moving objects')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('1200x600+200+50')
root.configure(bg='light green')

my_canvas = Canvas(root, bg='white', height=500, width=700)
my_canvas.pack()

btn_line = Button(root, text='Line', width=30, command=create_line)
btn_line.place(relx=0,rely=0.1)

root.mainloop()
```